# Return the column name that matches a WHERE clause in a query with mutliple WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm constructing a query to search for keywords in several fields in a database row, what I'd like to know is if there is any way to return which field the result was in.

For example, with a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE field1 LIKE "%keyword%" 
   OR field2 LIKE "%keyword%" 
   OR field3 LIKE "%keyword%"
```

If the keyword appears in `field2` I would like to return the row as well as additional information identifying that it was found in `field2`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not directly related but you might be interested in FULLTEXT search

Answer (score 3):

You can add some columns to indicate which field(s) matched the `where` clause. There's not a way to extract this information without putting it in the `select`.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    case when field1 LIKE "%keyword%" then 1 else 0 end as field1_found,
    case when field2 LIKE "%keyword%" then 1 else 0 end as field2_found,
    case when field3 LIKE "%keyword%" then 1 else 0 end as field3_found,
FROM table
WHERE field1 LIKE "%keyword%" 
   OR field2 LIKE "%keyword%" 
   OR field3 LIKE "%keyword%"
```

Answer (score 1):

But be aware if match multiple field only will return the first one.

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN field1 LIKE "%keyword%" THEN 'field1'
            WHEN field2 LIKE "%keyword%" THEN 'field2'
            WHEN field3 LIKE "%keyword%" THEN 'field3'
            ELSE 'no-match'
       END as matchField
FROM table
WHERE field1 LIKE "%keyword%" 
   OR field2 LIKE "%keyword%" 
   OR field3 LIKE "%keyword%"
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple way is like this:

```
SELECT 'field1', * 
FROM table
WHERE field1 LIKE "%keyword%" 
UNION
SELECT 'field2', * 
FROM table
WHERE field2 LIKE "%keyword%" 
UNION
SELECT 'field3', * 
FROM table
WHERE field3 LIKE "%keyword%"
```

Comment: I agree, it was my first thought as well. But doesn't this do a full table scan three times? I'm not sure but I assume so.

Comment: @PerlDog I think so, too (even it might be optimized by some engines, but I'm not sure at all). So it's esszentially matter of choice depending on context: my suggested solution has the advantage of simplicity, but is a good one only if there is not a too big number of records.

Comment: Again, I agree. It depends on the actual table. I like it because of the simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to concatenate them together:

```
SELECT t.*,
       concat_ws(',',
                 (case when field1 LIKE '%keyword%' then 'field1' end),
                 (case when field2 LIKE '%keyword%' then 'field2' end),
                 (case when field3 LIKE '%keyword%' then 'field3' end)
                ) as matchingFields
FROM table
WHERE field1 LIKE '%keyword%' OR
      field2 LIKE '%keyword%' OR
      field3 LIKE '%keyword%';
```

Note:  it is a good idea to use the (ANSI standard) single quote for string constants.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it in one field.

```
MariaDB []> SELECT
    ->   concat_ws( ', ',
    ->     IF(field1 LIKE '%keyword%','field1',NULL),
    ->     IF(field2 LIKE '%keyword%','field2',NULL),
    ->     IF(field3 LIKE '%keyword%','field3',NULL)
    ->   ) AS found_in, s.*
    ->   FROM searchtable s
    ->   WHERE field1 LIKE '%keyword%'
    ->   OR  field1 LIKE '%keyword%'
    ->   OR  field1 LIKE '%keyword%';
+------------------------+----+---------+---------+---------+
| found_in               | id | field1  | field2  | field3  |
+------------------------+----+---------+---------+---------+
| field1                 |  1 | keyword | NULL    | NULL    |
| field1, field3         |  4 | keyword | NULL    | keyword |
| field1, field2         |  6 | keyword | keyword | NULL    |
| field1, field2, field3 |  7 | keyword | keyword | keyword |
+------------------------+----+---------+---------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB []>
```